# How to record video and audio(both mic and speaker) audio using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, record, screen-recording

I am facing error when i try to record both audio **MIC and SPEAKER** new i need need command for record video and audio(both mic and speaker).

Tried bwlow command

ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Headset Microphone (Plantronics Blackwire 3225 Series)" -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -video_size 1920x1080 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -map 2 -map 0 -map 1 screen.avi

but its not working its throughing some error.

Comment: Some error... what is it? edit your question and add that details